# Using M-f in Jed

Tags: editor

In the Jed editor, you are supposed to be able to use M-f to move one word to the right.  However, when I try to use Alt-f, it triggers the File menu.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: As a workaround, try esc, f instead of alt-f. Are you on Windows? Personally I don't understand why anybody would want Emacs without the features ...

Comment: I'm on Linux. Esc-f opens the menu too.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but [this site](http://neilensperch.withtank.com/blog/2011/02/20/removing-alt-menu-accelerators-in-jed/) seems to have a solution:

```
. . . the solution is to place the following in $HOME/.jedrc

() = evalfile ("emacs");
```